# How to use hist for list and solve the error: "ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, plot

I use the following code to generate a list and want to draw distribution for it.

```
a = [random.randint(0, 1<<256) for i in range(500000)]
plt.hist(a, bins=400)
plt.show()
```

However I meet with some problems shown below:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

I tried to change the type into  `numpy.ndarray` using the following code, but it doesn't work.

```
x=np.array(a)
plt.hist(x, bins=400)
plt.show()
```

But I meet with the same error hint.
The following code works well for `numpy.ndarray`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(19680801)

mu, sigma = 100, 15
x = mu + sigma * np.random.randn(10000)

print(type(x))
# the histogram of the data
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x, 50, density=True, facecolor='g', alpha=0.75)


plt.xlabel('Smarts')
plt.ylabel('Probability')
plt.title('Histogram of IQ')
plt.text(60, .025, r'$\mu=100,\ \sigma=15$')
plt.xlim(40, 160)
plt.ylim(0, 0.03)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

But I want to figure out why mine doesn't work.

Comment: What does `np.array(a, dtype=float)` do.  `nan` is a float.

Comment: Oh it works ! thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`plt.hist(a, bin=400)` is not the correct input. What you should use is `plt.hist(a, bins=400)`. Also, `1<<256` seems to be a huge number, which does not seem right to me.

It seems that the problem is due to the too big 'int' object and hist can't handle it. When transferred to the float, it actually works.

```
num = 1<<256
a = [random.randint(0, num) for i in range(5000)]
b = [np.float(i) for i in a]
plt.hist(b, bins=400)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I have used bins, it's just a typing mistake.....So what if I really want to to get the distribution of 1<<256 ?

Comment: Try b = [np.float(i) for i in a] and you can use hist to plot b